# How to override getResources in Activity

Tags: android, resources, overriding

I've tried to extend `Resources` class, so i can override `getString(int id)` methode, so can do some effects to every `String` needed within my `Activity`, here i provide some my code:

```
public class CustomResource extends Resources {

    public CustomResource(AssetManager assets, DisplayMetrics metrics, Configuration config) {
        super(assets, metrics, config);
    }

    @Override
    public String getString(int id) throws NotFoundException {
        return super.getString(id) + " $$";
    }

}
```

and in my Activity :

```
CustomResource customResource;
    @Override
    public Resources getResources() {
        if (customResource == null) {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            super.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            customResource = new CustomResource(getAssets(), metrics, super.getResources().getConfiguration());
        }
        return customResource;
    }
```

but there's error shown on `Runtime`:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at com.test.TestActivity.getResources(TestActivity.java:75)

and it points to:

```
super.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

Comment: What if you use that line without super? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

Comment: I think the problem is , you are extending Resources and getWindowManager() is not part of that class, but you are using super.getWindowManager() which is causing the problem.

Comment: getWindowManager() is a method in Activity, not Resources.

Comment: @Will Kru : Same error, i just tried to put `super`, if the `super` is initialized before `TestActivity`

Comment: @sat: if you noticed the constructor of `Resources` needs it,
`public Resources(AssetManager assets, DisplayMetrics metrics, Configuration config)`

Comment: oops, I got confused there, so your getWindowManager is in your activity, instead of super.getWindowManager, just call getWindowManager()

Comment: @ sat, i told you , same error :( , i think in this case, the WindowManager not initialized yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a way:

```
private CustomResource customResource;

@Override
    public Resources getResources() {
        if (customResource == null) {
            customResource = new CustomResource(super.getAssets(), super.getResources().getDisplayMetrics(), super
                    .getResources().getConfiguration());
        }

        return customResource;
    }
```

even after adding this resources, its still doesn't override the Strings values coming from the LayoutInflator (ex. `setContentView(R.layout.sample)`)