# Create a class that extends Resources for API 25+

Tags: android, class, constructor, android-resources

I'd like to create an extended Resources class which is triggered on startup of the application.

```
public class ResourceUtil extends Resources {

    public ResourceUtil(AssetManager assets, DisplayMetrics metrics, Configuration config) {
        super(assets, metrics, config);
    }

}
```

However, I get the warning:

> *Resources(android.content.res.AssetManager,
>   android.util.DisplayMetrics, android.content.res.Configuration)' is
>   deprecated as of API 25*.

Is it possible to extend the Resources class, or is this functionality deprecated? I don't know how to construct it differently, in case there is a working constructor for API levels from 25 and up.

Edit: The [Android Resources page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources?hl=en) states:

> **Resources**(**AssetManager** assets, **DisplayMetrics** metrics, **Configuratio**n config)
>
> *This constructor is deprecated. Resources should not be constructed by apps. See* **Context.createConfigurationContext(Configuration)**.

So what exactly does Android want us to do from API 25 and up while maintaining the same functionality? Does it mean to abandon Resources class and get resources and override values in a Context and then pass that to the Activity/Fragments? Some direction would be highly appreciated.

Edit 2: I found [another thread from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889633/how-to-override-getresources-in-activity) which potentially could override an activity's public method getResources(). This answer from [Mohammed Ersan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/737925/mohammad-ersan) needs to be put inside an Activity:

```
ResourceUtil res;
@Override
public Resources getResources() {
    if (res == null) {
        res = new ResourceUtil(super.getAssets(),super.getResources().getDisplayMetrics(), super.getResources().getConfiguration());
    }
    return res;
}
```

However, even if the subclass is being used, it still won't work on API level 25 and higher.

Comment: Why do you need to extend the `Resources` class?

Comment: I'd like to override one of its public methods on startup. If a resource is of a particular attribute, I'd like to return a custom value. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to extend the Resources class

I'm not aware that this was ever particularly well-supported. For example: how precisely were you planning on forcing the framework to use your subclass?

> So what exactly does Android want us to do from API 25 and up while maintaining the same functionality?

As the documentation states, Google is not expecting you to create an instance of `Resources`. The framework creates instances of `Resources` that you use.

> Does it mean to abandon Resources class

Not really. There are plenty of places in Android — and in Java/Kotlin overall — where we use objects that are created by something else, such as the Android framework. Just because the framework creates instances instead of you does not mean that the class is being abandoned.

> If a resource is of a particular attribute, I'd like to return a custom value

You could try to fix the resource instead.

For example, suppose a library contributes a string resource `R.string.whatever` that maps to `"foo"` and you want it to map to `"bar"`. Just define `R.string.whatever` in your own resources, and it should override the string resource from the library.

Now, as it turns out, Android R debuted a `ResourceLoader` system, and I think there is a decent chance that `appcompat` will offer a backport in the coming months. At that point, you will be able to do more or less what you are looking to do, but with a custom `ResourceLoader` instead of a custom `Resources` subclass.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Not sure if it makes a difference, but what I'm trying to do is: 1. The user chooses a custom accent color; 2. The color(int) is stored in sharedPreferences; 3. On restart/next launch, the Resources class overrides "getColor" or "getIdentifier", determines whether its accent color/has attribute colorAccent, and then passes a value stored in sharedPreferences. I don't need to change values in xml resources, I just wish to override certain values on startup.

Comment: @ErlendK.H.: Well, again, how are you planning on forcing, say, `AppCompatActivity` to use your override? In a typical Android UI, you aren't the one using the resources most of the time -- other stuff that you use is what uses the resources. If the answer is that the only uses of the accent color that you care about are ones where you are using it directly, then just do your own lookaside in your own code. My assumption is that you expect *everything* to adopt your replacement accent color.

Comment: Hm, you're right, I may need to rephrase myself later as perhaps it's possible without a custom resource class and do with `onApplyThemeResource` for the activity (yes, it's extending `AppCompatActivity`)? And yes, I'd like to replace the accent color everywhere. What I'm doing now is manually change accent color of views, buttons, dialogs, etc., but it's very cluttering and inefficient.

Comment: @ErlendK.H.: I haven't tried playing with `onApplyThemeResource()`, so I cannot comment on that. Your current question assumes a solution (create a `Resources` subclass) to your real problem (provide a custom accent color to `AppCompatActivity` and its fragments). You might want to ask a separate Stack Overflow question that describes your real problem, based on the comments that you posted to the question and on this answer. There may be other solutions for overriding the accent color dynamically that I am not thinking of, and a question focused on that concern might get other answers.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I didn't know what approach to take to solve my issue, so I tried to subclass resources, but then you mentioned the question of how to use the subclass which is essential to know to make it work in the first place. What would you recommend me to do about this question?

Comment: @ErlendK.H.: I would leave it as-is. There is nothing wrong with the question... other than it is not helping you solve your problem. :-)